# MATLAB: Invalid file identifier despite of permissions

Tags: matlab

I am having the following code:

```
%% Methods
        function obj = loadDataGroundTruth(obj)

            dataFile = [obj.Configuration.dir.datafiles,'.csv'] ;

            % Open the data file
            fid = fopen(dataFile,'r+'); %# open csv file for reading

            % Scan data file until get to the segments part
            bIdFound = false ;
            while ((~feof(fid)) & (~bIdFound))
                line     = fgets(fid); %# read line by line
                stringId = sscanf(line,'%s'); %# sscanf can read only numeric data :(

                % Stop when we reach the trajectories section
                if strcmp(stringId, 'Segments')
                    bIdFound = true ;
                end
            end

            % Exit if there is not trajectories section in the file
            if (~bIdFound)
                % Close file descriptor
                fclose(fid);

                error('This data file does not contain motion information') ;
            end
```

which is supposed to lead the .csv files and do some work with them. However, I get the error specified in the title. Full trace can be seen below:

```
Error using feof
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in vicon.DataLoaderVICON/loadDataGroundTruth (line 99)
            while ((~feof(fid)) & (~bIdFound))

Error in vicon.DataLoaderVICON (line 82)
            obj.loadDataGroundTruth() ;

Error in vicon.DataLoaderVICONEdges (line 39)
            obj = obj@vicon.DataLoaderVICON(varargin{:})

Error in sequence.SequenceVICON (line 51)
            obj.DataLoader = vicon.DataLoaderVICONEdges(directory,...

Error in Lshape0001 (line 21)
seq              = sequence.SequenceVICON(SEQUENCE_NAME,...
```

The problem I suspect though is in this line:

```
 while ((~feof(fid)) & (~bIdFound))
```

Before anyone tells me to do so: I've already launched Matlab 2017b with sudo rights (Ubuntu 16.04) and I've added the entire folder to the path (with its subfolders).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a breakpoint to check if your fid value = -1. If yes it means that matlab can't read or write `fopen('yourfile')` properly. Maybe your csv file is only in read mode.

Comment: Yes, it is -1. But I open the file with r+, does not it mean read and write mode?

Comment: That's right, you ask the permission to read and write, but you also need to check if your file allow thoses permissions. You can check that with the `ls -l` command in your linux terminal. Check also that dataFile exist with `exist(dataFile, 'file')`

Comment: Well, the file exists for sure, it is there I can see it. As for the file permissions, the tag I see is `-rw-rw-r--`, which means read and write, I suppose?

Comment: Just to be sure you can add the write permissions for all kind of user with `chmod a+w yourfile.csv`... And anyway check if the `dataFile` exist, because the path of your file can be wrong.

Comment: That returns 0, which means the path is wrong, or?

Comment: Indeed, so you only have to check what's wrong in your path now. Try to use the  full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured out, thanks to contributions of user [obchardon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4363864/obchardon).

I've noticed that the path had somehow `./` included in it as well, which shouldn't have been the case. The file I was trying to run probably was written in a Windows machine, and thus had different symbols/notation in the path. Once I printed the path it was trying to load the file from, I've noticed that it should not have `./`. I removed that from the path and it worked.